# URL rewrite for non SEO friendly URLs

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite a couple of URLs which are unfriendly for SEO.

**Current URL:**
domain.com/profile.php?user=chris

**Should be:**
domain.com/profile/chris

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:
I’ve tried this....

```
location /profile {
rewrite ^/profile/?$ /profile.php?user=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just updated post with what I’ve done so far.